# C# value assignment to object reference directly

Tags: c#, .net, assignment-operator

```
Person p = "Any Text Value";
```

Person is a class.

Is this anyway possible in C#.

I answered as no, but according to the interviewer this is possible. He didn't gave me any clues also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using an [implicit conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit). It could be argued that this would be an *abuse* of an implicit conversion, given that it's not obvious exactly what `"Any Text Value"` should represent in this case. Here's an example of the code that would make your example succeed:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Person(string name) =>
        new Person { Name = name }; 
}
```

Here's a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xTRGY5) example.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `implicit` like so:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public sealed class Person
    {
        public Person(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public static implicit operator Person(string name)
        {
            return new Person(name);
        }

        public string Name { get; }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Person person = "Fred";

            Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

However, explicit conversion is preferred - you should generally [only use `implicit` for things like inventing a new numeric type such as `Complex`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/284359/when-should-i-use-cs-implicit-type-conversion-operator).